# nginx internal rewrite to mask true uri

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but what I'm trying to do is setup an internal rewrite in nginx so that when a customer accesses /foo it returns the content of /bar

so far I've tried;

```
location ~ ^/foo$ {
     rewrite ^/foo$ /bar last;
}
```

and

```
location ~ ^/foo$ {
     try_files $uri /bar;
}
```

Neither of which seem to do what I'm after, seems like something that should be very simple is being a complete pain.

Comment: How does it fail to work specifically?

Comment: In case of the rewrite it just does a normal redirect that is visible to the user, the second version doesn't appear to do anything at all

Comment: Your rewrite should not cause a visible redirect, so it's probable that your application itself issues redirects.

Comment: The application doesn't do any redirects of any kind